# Deserialize json string to c# object using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, serialization, json.net

I have been working with the project, where i have to make external RESTful service call to get some data.

The problem i'm facing here is, the response i'm getting from the service is different on different scenario. For example.

On one scenario, i'm getting below response

```
{  
   "id":3000056,
   "posted_date":"2016-04-15T07:16:47+00:00",
   "current_status":"initialized",
   "customer":{  
        "name" : "George",
        "lastName" : "Mike"
   },
   "application_address":{
        "addressLine1" : "Lin1",
        "addressLine2" : "Lin2",
   }

}
```

In the other scenario, im getting below response

```
 {  
   "id":3000057,
   "posted_date":"2016-04-15T07:16:47+00:00",
   "current_status":"initialized",
   "customer":[],
   "application_address":[]

}
```

The problem here is, i have below model, and i'm deserializing it by newtonsoft deserailization.

```
public class Response
    {

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("posted_date")]
        public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("current_status")]
        public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customer")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("application_address")]
        public ApplicationAddress ApplicationAddress { get; set; }


    }


public Class Customer
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public classs ApplicationAddress
{
public string addreesLine1{ get; set; }
public string addreesLine1{ get; set; }
}
```

For the first response, it will desrialize. But for the second response, the response is not getting deserialized as the response contains `[]` for `Customer` and `ApplicationAddrees` object. While deserializing, it is treating as a array, but actually it is not.

Note : Below code i'm using for Deserializing.
Response response =                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

Is there any configuration we can do before serializing? Is newtonsoft facilitate that feature?

Thanks .

Comment: Can you please share your deserialization call?

Comment: For the different scenarios use different classes to deserialize into. The first example use the class you have, the second use a class with List<Customer>, List<ApplicationAddresses> properties. You could use a base class for the shared properties. Is it a single endpoint you are calling for the different scenarios?

Comment: @TimBourguignon , i have update the question with deserialization code.

Comment: @PaRsH Looks like another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186715/deserialize-json-single-string-to-array/31188918#31188918) I've answered

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that there will be no arrays in this properties, than you can consider using **JsonConverter** like this:

```
public class FakeArrayToNullConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return  token.ToObject<T>();

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then put additional attribure to your model:

```
    [JsonProperty("customer")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FakeArrayToNullConverter<Customer>))]
    public Customer Customers { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("application_address")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FakeArrayToNullConverter<ApplicationAddress>))]
    public ApplicationAddress ApplicationAddressList { get; set; }
```

And when in your JSON string  for this properties it will be an array `[]`, you will simply deserialize it with `null` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instruct deserialize to handle "[]" as something different as it represents an array (are you sure you never will get customers and addresses in those arrays??)

So you could [deserialize to an anonymous type](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) and then map it to your structure.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure that, we wont get Customer as arrary. It will be always a single object.

Comment: Ok so I would use anonymous to handle this case

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but can you check if this works:

```
public class ApplicationAddress
{
    private readonly string[] _array = new string[2];
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get { return _array[index]; }
        set { _array[index] = value; }
    }
    public string addreesLine1
    {
        get { return this[0]; }
        set { this[0] = value; }
    }
    public string addreesLine2
    {
        get { return this[1]; }
        set { this[1] = value; }
    }
}
```